# Ansible Playbook Variable Prompt Not Working

Tags: ansible, yaml

What I'm trying to accomplish for Ansible is to prompt for a local username to be deleted on a Windows machine. So far the prompt works but after putting in the prompt, the playbook throws the error:

> FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'usernametodelete' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/Users/admin/Desktop/AnsiblePlaybooks/PromptTest.yml': line 10, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n   - name: Removing user that was typed in\n     ^ here\n"}

Here's my YAML file that I've created:

```
- hosts: win 
  vars_prompt:
    - name: usernametodelete
      prompt: "What is the username to be deleted?"
      private: no


- hosts: win
  tasks:
   - name: Removing user that was typed in
     win_user:
      name: '{{usernametodelete}}'
      state: absent
```

Comment: This isn't a programming question; you might have better luck asking over on [sf]. Have you tried quoting that value?

Comment: Well, it's sort of a programming question (it's about variable scope).  A playbook is just as much "source code" as any other interpreted language. The problem is that the variables defined by `vars_prompt` are only valid *for that play*. You are trying to reference the variable in a play other than which it was defined.

Comment: ...but it is a duplicate.